# Create dynamic component with constructor arguments

Tags: angular, dynamic, constructor, arguments, components

Is there a way to **dynamically** create a component which requires constructor arguments?

To clarify: Im creating the component with a ComponentFactory as follows:

```
const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent);
const componentRef: ComponentRef<MyComponent> = this.myInsertionpoint.createComponent(factory);
```

The component has a readonly field which is supposed to be set via the constructor.

```
export class MyComponent {
  private readonly _myField: MyField;

  constructor(myField: MyField) {
    this._myField = myField;
  }

...
}
```

Im aware i could remove the readonly an set the field
like

```
component.instance.myField = "myValue";
```

... but i would prefer to leave it as it is as the field should only
be set on creation of the component.

Comment: Yeah well if you give it a value out of the declaration, he's not readonly.

Comment: I would like to set myField only once when creating the object. If the object would be created by using the 'new'-keyword i would simply pass it as constructor argument. My question is: how can this be achieved when dynamically creating the object with a component-resolver-factory-

Comment: That can be done with the answer I have provided and that you rejected, without even testing it.